# Transform a 9x9 list so that each row contains the 3x3 block

Tags: haskell

This is my solution which works, but there probably is a better way to write this.

Basically I have a list with 9 rows each containing 9 elements, representing a 9x9 sudoku as seen in the example. I want to tranform that list so that each row corresponds to the 3x3 blocks in a sudoku

How can I improve this?

```
-- returns 9 rows that corresponds to the 3x3 blocks in a sudoku
-- splits the list, transposes, concats, and then combines into 9 rows
all3x3blocks :: [Block] -> [Block] 
all3x3blocks b = combineList (concat (transpose (splitList b)))

-- splits up each of the 9 rows into 3 parts with 3 elements in each
splitList :: [Block] -> [[Block]]
splitList b = [mySplit 3 x | x <- b ]

-- splits a list into n sized lists
mySplit :: Int -> Block -> [Block]
mySplit _ [] = []
mySplit n list = firstSplit : (mySplit n rest)
  where
    (firstSplit,rest) = splitAt n list

-- combines a split row, by combining 3 parts into 1 row with 9 elements
combineList :: [Block] -> [Block]
combineList [] = []
combineList list = concat(split) : combineList rest
    where (split, rest) = splitAt 3 list

type Block = [Maybe Int]

example :: [Block]
example =
    [ [Just 3, Just 6, Nothing,Nothing,Just 7, Just 1, Just 2, Nothing,Nothing]
    , [Nothing,Just 5, Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Just 1, Just 8, Nothing]
    , [Nothing,Nothing,Just 9, Just 2, Nothing,Just 4, Just 7, Nothing,Nothing]
    , [Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Just 1, Just 3, Nothing,Just 2, Just 8]
    , [Just 4, Nothing,Nothing,Just 5, Nothing,Just 2, Nothing,Nothing,Just 9]
    , [Just 2, Just 7, Nothing,Just 4, Just 6, Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing]
    , [Nothing,Nothing,Just 5, Just 3, Nothing,Just 8, Just 9, Nothing,Nothing]
    , [Nothing,Just 8, Just 3, Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Just 6, Nothing]
    , [Nothing,Nothing,Just 7, Just 6, Just 9, Nothing,Nothing,Just 4, Just 3]
    ]

-- Desired outcome after transformation
[[Just 3,Just 6,Nothing,Nothing,Just 5,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Just 9]
,[Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Just 4,Nothing,Nothing,Just 2,Just 7,Nothing]
,[Nothing,Nothing,Just 5,Nothing,Just 8,Just 3,Nothing,Nothing,Just 7]
,[Nothing,Just 7,Just 1,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Just 2,Nothing,Just 4]
,[Nothing,Just 1,Just 3,Just 5,Nothing,Just 2,Just 4,Just 6,Nothing]
,[Just 3,Nothing,Just 8,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Just 6,Just 9,Nothing]
,[Just 2,Nothing,Nothing,Just 1,Just 8,Nothing,Just 7,Nothing,Nothing]
,[Nothing,Just 2,Just 8,Nothing,Nothing,Just 9,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing]
,[Just 9,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Just 6,Nothing,Nothing,Just 4,Just 3]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially the same as you did, but I would write it as a pipeline:

```
sudokuClusters :: [[c]] -> [ [[c]] ]   -- note this is polymorphic: no reason
sudokuClusters =                       -- it should only work with `Maybe Int`!
      concat              -- gather 3×3-blocks from each triplet of rows
    . map transpose       -- combine cell-triplets that were vertical neighbours
    . splitsEach 3        -- partition rows
    . map (splitsEach 3)  -- partition each row

splitsEach :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitsEach _ [] = []
splitsEach n l = firstSplit : splitsEach n rest
 where (firstSplit, rest) = splitAt n l
```

An interesting, more general solution would be:

```
recluster :: (∀ x . [x] -> [[x]]) -> [[c]] -> [ [[c]] ]
recluster f = concatMap transpose . f . map f

sudokuClusters = recluster (splitsEach 3)
```

Comment: I not sure the output is quite the same as the original. I think perhaps the `concat` would need to be `map (map concat)`?

Comment: @ryachza: I don't know which function “the original” is supposed to be. `all3x3blocks` certainly has another result – the 3×3-blocks are represented as flat lists of length 9. I daresay it's trivial to get there from my solution.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the `all3x3blocks` and the "desired outcome" section. I agree it is trivial for some (as my comment shows - a very minor change), but not necessarily for all, so I figured I would mention it in case a more direct comparison was preferred.

Comment: Actually, in fact I messed it up myself. It would actually need to be `concat . map (map concat)`.

Comment: @ryachza or `map concat . concat`.

Comment: Interesting solutions, I will try to integrate them, and I should really try to make my functions more general

Comment: fyi - `splitsEach` is also known as [__`chunksOf`__](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.2/docs/Data-List-Split.html#v:chunksOf) in the `Data.List.Split` library